Managing Transactions Across Multiple Tenants with Separate Schemas in Spring Boot JPA
I'm working on a multi-tenant system where each tenant's data is stored in a separate schema. I've configured multi-tenancy following the guide on Baeldung, but I'm facing challenges with managing transactions across the tenants using Spring Boot and JPA.
Here's the method I'm using to update a user profile across all tenants:
@Transactional
public void updateUserProfile(Long id, List<Tenant> tenants, String link) {
    UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.findById(id)
                          .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("UserProfile not found"));

    for (Tenant tenant : tenants) {
        TenantContext.setTenantId(tenant.getId()); // Set the tenant context
        userProfile.setServiceType("Hans");
        userProfileRepository.save(userProfile);
        // Reset TenantContext or set it for the next tenant as needed
    }

    TenantContext.clear(); // Clear or reset the TenantContext
    userProfile.setLink(link);
    userProfileRepository.save(userProfile);
}

In this setup, I aim to update the serviceType for a UserProfile across all tenants and then update a link for the profile outside the tenant loop.
The problem arises when attempting to update the userProfile for each tenant within the loop. Despite updating the TenantContext to a new tenant ID, the datasource does not change, and the updates don't reflect in the intended tenant's schema.
Questions:
How can I ensure that the datasource switches according to the TenantContext within a transactional method?
Is there a need to adjust the transaction management strategy to support dynamic datasource routing in a multi-tenant setup?
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

In a transaction, the tenant is selected only once and cannot be changed.
Remove @Transactional and code to begin/commit the transaction in the loop.
You can get current tenant id from entityManager
var tenantId = entityManager.unwrap(SharedSessionContract.class).getTenantIdentifier();

